# Finding multiple maxima in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, max

I have written a program in visual basic and want it to display the maximum value that is entered into an array. Sometimes the same value will be entered 2 or more times and I need some way of detecting this and informing the user of it, at the end of the program.

Currently I am performing a find max then doing linear search through array items. If the item is = to the max then I set an array boolean flag to true. Only problem I have is displaying the multi max as I need to use the positions in the boolean array to detect which items in the values array appeared equal max number of times, if that makes sense. Is it possible to perform a fixed loop of a MsgBox("...") without repeating the text, just altering the value of i(the position in the values array being accessed).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** 
Code from comment

```
max=0 
for i = 1 to 4 
if number(i)>number(max) then max=i 
next 

for i = 0 to 4 
if number(i)=number(max) then flag(i)=true 
next 
Msgbox("the biggest number you entered was" & number(max))
```

Comment: Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: 'max=0
for i = 1 to 4
if number(i)>number(max) then
max=i
next
for i = 0 to 4
if number(i)=number(max) then
flag(i)=true
next
Msgbox("the biggest number you entered was" & number(max))'

I only really want this msgbox to display if there is only 1 occurrence of the max but I don't know how to run a secondary msgbox displaying how many times the max occured

Comment: You want to show a msgbox for each of the items that are equal to number(max)?

Comment: I want a msgbox to show stating how many times the number(max) occurred but a different msgbox to display if number(max) only appeared once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested...

```
Dim n as Long

For i = 0 to 4
    If number(i) = number(max) Then
         n = n + 1
    End If
Next i

Dim msg As String

msg = "max = " & number(max)
If n > 1 Then
    msg = msg & " which appeared " & n & " times"
End If

MsgBox msg
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I was perhaps over complicating things.